# loop with array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

i have this code to get three values.

```
 success: function(json){
                        $msg1 = parseFloat(json[0].valor1);
                        $msg2 = parseFloat(json[1].valor2);
                        $msg3 = parseFloat(json[2].valor3);
                    }
```

but now suppose that i need 200 values.
I'm not doing 200 times ...

```
                        $msg1 = parseFloat(json[0].valor1);
                        $msg2 = parseFloat(json[1].valor2);
                        $msg3 = parseFloat(json[2].valor3);
                        //...
                        $msg200 = parseFloat(json[199].valor200);
```

so, i need a loop, correct?

i tried something like this

```
                        for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
                        $msg(i+1) = parseFloat(json[i].valor(i+1));
                        i++;
                        }
```

but didn't work

thanks

Comment: Why do you need 200 variables? Why not have one array with 200 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$msg = [];
for (var i=0; i<200; i++) {
    $msg.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor"+i]));       
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is why The Creator gave the world arrays.

```
var msgs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
  msgs.push(parseFloat(json[i]['valor' + i]));
```

Note that your JSON data should also keep those "valor" properties as arrays, though in JavaScript you can deal with a bizarre naming scheme like that as in the example above.

*edit* — oops, typos fixed :-)

Comment: you code give me an error syntax - http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php. i think you forget a ]

Comment: no problem :) one more question please Pointy. Anteriorly i access to the values with y: $msg1. With your code, how i do? i try  $msg[i]= msgs.push(// but i get $msg is not defined error

Comment: Well if you set this up as an array, then it would be "msgs[1]" instead of "msgs1".

Comment: i just copy paste your code and change the y:$msg1 to   y: msgs[0], and i get msgs is not defined y: msgs[0],

Comment: @Wire Creation OK two things: first, move the definition of "msgs" (the `var msgs = [];` line) outside of the "$(document).ready()" block.  Second thing is that you will have to delay the dojo setup code that *uses* "msgs" until after the ajax call completes. Maybe put it in a function and call it from the ajax handler. (If it's not clear you should probably post a separate question about that part.)

Comment: at this moment i don't get any message of error , but the chart is not draw. i will accept your answer and post another question. The problem is other now.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Pointy or:

```
                var msgs = [];
                for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
                $msg[i] = parseFloat(eval('json[' + i + '].valor(' + i + '+1)'));
                i++;
                }
```

However eval is slow, so Pointy's answer is better.

Comment: But what exactly is "$msg(i+1)" supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = json.someid;// or json['someid'];
// json is returned not an array
var msgs = [];
$.each(array, function(index, e) {
    msgs.push(parseFloat[e['valor' + index], 10); 
});
```

when using parseFloat use the radix parameter unless you want bad things to happen;

javascript needs to be told for example not to parse octal;